# Saving images to gallery from the RecyclerView

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview

Am having a RecyclerView which shows List of Images and Texts , but what i want is when i click on any of the images the image is saved to the gallery.

Below is the Method am having for saving the Image but i have failed to connect it to the RecyclerView to detect each image to save.

```
  public  void SaveImage(){
        imagePost.buildDrawingCache();

        Bitmap bmp = imagePost.getDrawingCache();

        File storageLoc = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); //context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

        File file = new File(storageLoc, "Pixsar" + ".jpg");

        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();

            scanFile(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(file));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved to gallery ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    private static void scanFile(Context context, Uri imageUri){
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        scanIntent.setData(imageUri);
        context.sendBroadcast(scanIntent);

    }
```

SO this is My FirebaseRecyclerView.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, BlogViewHolder>(Posts.class,
                    R.layout.item_activity,
                    BlogViewHolder.class,
                    mDatabase) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Posts model, final int position) {

                    final String key_post = getRef(position).getKey();
                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getEventTitle());
                    viewHolder.setDesc(model.getEventDescription());
                    viewHolder.setImage(c, model.getEventImage());

                    final String key_post_image = getRef(position).getKey();




                }
            };
```

And this is My ViewHolder Class

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        View mView;

        private ImageView imagePost;
        private  ImageView save_image_blog;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
            imagePost =(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            save_image_blog =(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.save_image_blog);



        }
```

so i want the Image loaded in `imagePost ImageView` in a RecyclerView to saved in the gallery .

How can i attach that SavingImage Method to `imagePost` `ImageView`

Comment: You haven't set an View.OnClickListener for the image

Comment: Yeah i have done it , but it says Null Pointer ,may be yo help me on it @Nic

Comment: A null pointer means you haven't initialised a variable. You'll probably need to debug that yourself. Just look at the stack trace and you can find what is null that you are trying to access.